# Remove input field validation message on submit

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, input, submit

I have this input field:

```
        <input type="text" name="email"
    id="<?php if(isset($error['email'])){echo "email";} ?>"
    placeholder="Enter email address"
    value="<?php if (!isset($error['email'])) echo "";
    else if($error['email'] == 'Enter email address') { echo "";}
    else if($error['email'] == 'Enter a valid email address') { echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES)." - Enter a valid email address";} ?>"
    class="<?php if(isset($error['email'])){echo "error-found";} else { echo "no-error";} ?>"
 tabindex="1">
```

and this Javascript code:

```
var inputBox = document.getElementById("email");
inputBox.onfocus = function(){
    inputBox.value = inputBox.value.replace(" - Enter a valid email address","");
    inputBox.onfocus = null;
}
```

which removes the validation message when user goes to the input field.

This works as required however when user does not go to the input field and submits the form, the validation message is added again to the end of the value of the input field.

I want the message removed on submit so that this issue would be solved.

I tried through PHP but it's not working

```
else if($error['email'] == 'Enter a valid email address' &&
strpos(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES), ' - Enter a valid email address') !== false){
echo str_replace(" - Enter a valid email address","",htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES));}
```

Therefore I would like to continue via Javascript, if anyone can point it out to me.
Much appreciated your response.

Comment: Your error message should be outside the input box. Also `type=email` already validates the email.

Comment: You can add a `<span class="error">Email is not valid</span>` just below the input to show the error message. If you put it in the email field it will continue to send it self with the form data.

Comment: @ariel - That's what I want to achieve, have the error messages displayed inside the input box and it's working fine for now.

Comment: @Prikesh Savla I know that but for better aesthetics I would want it inside the input box.

Comment: Javascript should do it, what I need now is a way to remove that error message when user presses submit. I tried making another Javascript function as above "inputBox.value.replace" and "inputBox.onfocus = null;" to change it to "inputBox.onsubmit = null;" but it doesn't work that way ... what would be the right way to do it ?

Comment: that is really not a good way to di it. modify your users response and send it or show error messages in a text box. you can use the css :after pseudo to show the text. and position it in a way that will show as inside. But this is really a bad way to show error messages.

Comment: ok thanks for letting me know. I have already switched to a different way